# AsyncCallback, call from different class and multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I'm trying to build simple class using [Singleton Pattern](http://codebender.denniland.com/a-singleton-base-class-to-implement-the-singleton-pattern-in-c/).

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have in my main class 2 functions responsible for handling results of async method call. One will handle correct results and second all errors.

Class that does all async operations looks like this:

```
class EWS : SingletonBase<EWS>
{
    private EWS()
    {
        //private constructor
    }


    private int LongRunningMethod(Action<string> error)
    {
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(i);
            x += i;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        //here I can do try...catch and then call error("Description")
        return x;
    }

    public class CommandAndCallback<TSuccess, TError>
    {
        public TSuccess Success { get; set; }
        public TError Error { get; set; }
    }

    public void DoOperation(Action<int> success, Action<string> error)
    {
        Func<Action<string>, int> dlgt = LongRunningMethod;
        //Func<Action<string>, int> dlgt = new Func<Action<string>, int>(LongRunningMethod);

        CommandAndCallback<Action<int>, Action<string>> callbacks = new CommandAndCallback<Action<int>, Action<string>>() { Success = success, Error = error };

        IAsyncResult ar = dlgt.BeginInvoke(error,MyAsyncCallback, callbacks); 
    }

    public void MyAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //how to access success and error here???
        int s ;
        Func<Action<string>, int> dlgt = (Func<Action<string>,int>)ar.AsyncState;
        s = dlgt.EndInvoke(ar);
        //here I need to call success or error that were passed to DoOperation
    }
}
```

In my main class I would like to call my method like so:

```
private void Operation_OK(int count)
{
     //here handle OK
}

private void Operation_ERROR(string error)
{
     //here handle ERROR
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EWS.Instance.DoOperation(Operation_OK, Operation_ERROR);
}
```

**How should I modify my EWS class so I can call it like shown above.

How to use lambda expressions instead delegates?**

Is this a good idea to call methods like this? I need to have 2 or 3 methods in my class and be able to call them in all forms independent.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
private void MyAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int s;
    MethodDelegate dlgt = (MethodDelegate)ar.AsyncState;
    s = dlgt.EndInvoke(ar);
    MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
}
```

with

```
private void MyAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int s;
    MethodDelegate dlgt = (MethodDelegate)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
    s = dlgt.EndInvoke(ar);
    MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
}
```

Updated answer

IAsyncResult ar = dlgt.BeginInvoke(error,MyAsyncCallback, callbacks,error);

now in MyAsyncCallback

```
string error = (string) ar.AsyncState;
if(error!=null)
    return;
```

Comment: Thanks for such a fast answer :) But I would like to remove declaring delegates, instead use `Action` or `Func` if it is possible. Another question is how to pass my error callback to `LongRunningMethod` and how to access both error and success callbacks in `MyAsyncCallback`

Comment: you can use Func<> if you have a return type else you can use Action<>

Comment: Could You look at my edited code? I need to pass `error` to `LongRunningMethod` and `error` and `success` to `MyAsyncCallback`

Comment: and recieve it in callback as ar.AsyncState

Comment: Please look at my answer, this basically works fine, but I have still one problem-how to stop `MyAsyncCallback` if in my `LongRunningMethod` I call error?

Comment: pass an object in your beginInvoke and if that object has some value exit from MyAysncCallback

Answer (score 0):

Got this working:

```
    private int LongRunningMethod(Action<string> error)
    {
        int x = 0;
        try
        {
            x = 20 / x;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error("Bad error!");
        }
        return x;
    }

    public class CommandAndCallback<TCallback, TError>
    {
        public TCallback Callback { get; set; }
        public TError Error { get; set; }
        public Func<Action<string>, int> Delegate { get; set; }
    }

    public void DoOperation(Action<int> callback, Action<string> error)
    {
        Func<Action<string>, int> dlgt = LongRunningMethod;
        CommandAndCallback<Action<int>, Action<string>> callbacks = new CommandAndCallback<Action<int>, Action<string>>() { Callback = callback, Error = error, Delegate=dlgt };
        IAsyncResult ar = dlgt.BeginInvoke(error,MyAsyncCallback, callbacks); 
    }

    private void MyAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int s ;
        CommandAndCallback<Action<int>, Action<string>> callbacks= (CommandAndCallback<Action<int>, Action<string>>)ar.AsyncState;
        s = callbacks.Delegate.EndInvoke(ar);
        callbacks.Success(s);
    }
```

This works just fine.
There is just one problem, if in `LongRunningMethod` I call error method `MyAsyncCallback` is also called.

So this is only one thing to fix, so when error method is called `MyAsyncCallback` won't get called.